# Python merge excel documents with dynamic columns

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlwt

I have several thousand excel documents. All of these documents are 95% the same in terms of column headings. However, since they are not 100% identical, I cannot simply merge them together and upload it into a database without messing up the data.

Would anyone happen to have a library or an example that they've ran into that would help?

Answer (score 0):

If a large proportion of them are similar, and this is a one-off operation it may be worth your while coding the solution for the majority and handling the other documents (or groups of them if they are similar) separately. If using Python to do this you could simply build a dynamic query where the columns that are present in a given excel sheet are built into the INSERT statements. Of course, this assumes that your database table allows for NULLs or that a default value is present on the columns that aren't in a given document.

Comment: I get these excel documents everyday via email, and i'm looking for a way to automate this process. I haven't picked a database yet. But i'm leaning towards MongoDB.

Comment: Depending on how you want to represent the data in the database, and what it's eventually going to be used for, you could simply make a new collection in each database for each excel file.

Comment: The data that is contained in the excel documents is fault codes from heavy and medium duty trucks. I'm definitely wanting it to be a relational data base.

Comment: In that case MongoDB is probably not going to be a good choice- by design it's a document-orientated rather than a relational data store.

Comment: Any recommendations to a db that would allow me to dump a few thousand excel documents and then create join queries to the VIN column?

Comment: MySQL or PostgreSQL would probably be a good starting point, but you will need to set up a suitable table structure.